# What's the difference between Axios.js and API RestFul?

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

i was studying somethings of JavaScript and Node.Js and it came to me a doubt.

What's the difference between Axios.js and API Rest?, the two do the same thing
 ? If not, what's the diference ?

Comment: axios is a library, and API REST doesn't mean anything. Clarify your reference: API REST - What are you asking about?

Comment: Do you know what an API is? Do you know what REST is? If not, I would start with learning that...

Comment: Also, the usual term is "REST API" or "RESTful API"

Comment: @MattBrowne - that still is not comparable to a library. I would then ask "which one?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q:** What's the difference between Axios.js and API Rest? Do they do the same thing?

**A:** They are two completely different thing.

I see `REST` API as a form of standard for building your service. Whereas Axios.js is just a `JavaScript` library for you to make `HTTP` calls to an external service.

What is this `service`? An application you build using your `Node.js` would typically expose 1 or more endpoints for a client (e.g. web-client) to hit to accomplish a task.

Example of tasks can be like

- Create a User
- View the details of a User
- Modify User details
- Delete User

What is an endpoint? It is just an `URL`, e.g. `http://www.myservice.com/do_stuff`, `do_stuff` would be your endpoint.

What a RESTFUL web service/API means is that you would design your endpoint to be something human readable. For instance for each of the task described above, the standard states that it will be best to design the endpoints in such a way that each task would have its own endpoint that is descriptive enough to a human.

Like;

1. `http://www.myservice.com/create_user`
2. `http://www.myservice.com/view_user/`
3. `http://www.myservice.com/update_user/`
4. `http://www.myservice.com/delete_user/`

comparing to having just one endpoint `do_stuff` which can just do everything.

So what is `Axion.js`? It is simply a Javascript library which your client application can use to make `HTTP` call to 1 of those endpoint services described above.

Comment: Many thanks for your response <3. 

But to make it clearer to me. Example: I have a project that takes some data from a `JSON` that is a `URL` and render on the screen, using `axios.js` being service, correct?. ** URL is: localhost: 9000 / people, and at this URL there is a `JSON` and I get data and manipulate it, such as displaying data in an alert with axios.js


and REST would be sending data to an API to return an expected result, is that it?

Comment: That project, which renders stuff onto the screen is a web application. Sounds like your web application is using the Javascript library `axion.js` to use a service provided your `nodeJs` server by doing a `GET http` request to an `endpoint`. That is, `localhost:9000/people` is your endpoint and it is providing a service for others to retrieve some JSON data about people. `REST` is just an architecture design which is about how to properly name your service's endpoint.

Comment: Now, I understood completely, thank you very much, it helped me a lot <3